# Can't retrieve bluetooth device names or unique identifier

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, bluetooth

I need to identify Bluetooth devices in proximity to other devices for my iOS application.

I am using the following:

```
func didReadPeripheral(_ peripheral: CBPeripheral, rssi: NSNumber) {
print("peripheral name", peripheral,to: &logger)
if peripheral.name != nil {
}
}
```

This isn't working for me.

Suppose there are two users that are scanning the room for bluetooth access points. Also assume these are the real bluetooth access points in a room: 1,2, 3,4,5,6

User 1 detects  picks up 1 and 2 and labels aa and bb. Whereas user 2 picks up 1,2,3, 4,5,6 and labels zz,,xx, yy,tt,uu,WW.

It seems as though one of the phones are "relabelling"the access points and there is no consistency between the two users.

Has anyone solved this issue?

Comment: The identifier of a discovered peripheral is unique to that peripheral on the device that discovered it. Identifiers are not exchangeable between iOS devices. iBeacon UUIDs are discovered consistently.

Comment: How do i implement iBeacon UUIDs ?

Comment: You need to have iBeacon hardware

Comment: No the solution can't have any hardware component aside from an iphone

Comment: You mentioned "Bluetooth access points";  I assumed these weren't phones. iPhones can advertise a BLE service and then the other iPhones can connect, briefly, to that service and read a unique identifier from a BLE characteristic.

Comment: I  just need a list of all devices that are in "discovery mode"

Comment: There isn't a "discovery mode" in Bluetooth Low Energy.  You need the device to advertise a GATT service and then other devices can look for that service.